# Angle Cosin Between Acceleration and Velocity Vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Have here $r_{t} = (e^t \times sin (2t))\hat i + (e^t cos(2t))\hat j + (2e^t) \hat k$, which is the position vector of a particle over a curve at $t$ instant.

Which is the angle cosin between the aceleration and velocity vectors with $t=0$?

Would anyone answer?

Comment: Do you mean $sin$ instead of $sen$?

Comment: Thats right, just corrected!